# EF 6 with Oracle - how to join on date field?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF 6 with Oracle and I'm trying to do a multiple column join using an Employee number and Date field. I can't get the LEFT OUTER JOIN to work properly and I'm pretty sure it's because of the date. I know dates in Oracle can be tricky and I usually have to use the "TO_DATE" function to strip out the HH:mm:ss and only use the mm/dd/yyyy. However, I don't know how this can be accomplished using EF.

I tried using the .ToShortDateString to strip out only the mm/dd/yyyy but I had to then Parse it back to a DateTime in order to get past the following error: `The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type interface failed in the call to 'join'`. From the research on that error it looks as though my "reportDate" has to be of type DateTime in order to match the h.REPORT_DATE (DATETIME) field in Oracle. The problem with Parsing it back to DateTime is that it then becomes "mm/dd/yyyy 12:00:00 AM" and causes the data to not JOIN.

Here is some the code.

```
DateTime reportDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());

var data = (from e in db.SAP_EMPLOYEE
    join h in db.ABSMGMT_HOURS on new { a = e.EMP, b = reportDate } 
                                    equals new { a = h.EMP_ID, b = h.REPORT_DATE}
    into t from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Anyone know how to work with mm/dd/yyyy date formats with EF 6 and Oracle?

Comment: if it works with EF6... `trunc(date)`  that way your matching on DD/MM/YYYY only.  no time portion.  `Select case when sysdate-2/24=sysdate then 1 else 0 end,
case when trunc(sysdate-2/24)=trunc(sysdate) then 1 else 0 end from dual` trunc truncates the time off

Comment: I know in SQL I would use trunc(date) but how do I use that with EF? EF doesn't have trunc() as a function that I can tell.

Comment: `var x = myContext.MyTable.Where(i => (i.MyDateColumn >= DateTime.ToDay) && (i.MyDateColumn < DateTime.ToDay.AddDays(1)))` from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84d4e18b-7545-419b-9826-53ff1a0e2a62/ignore-time-portion-of-datetime-in-a-linq-to-entity-framework-query?forum=csharpgeneral  But I'm just guessing here, as I'm not an entity-framework user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research from some suggested articles I think I've found a hack for Oracle. Basically you have to compare the Year, the Month, and the Day separately. It's definitely not elegant but looks like it works.

```
var data = (from e in db.SAP_EMPLOYEE
            join h in db.ABSMGMT_HOURS on new { a = e.EMP, b = DateTime.Today.Year, c = DateTime.Today.Month, d = DateTime.Today.Day }
                                            equals new { a = h.EMP_ID, b = h.REPORT_DATE.Year, c = h.REPORT_DATE.Month, d = h.REPORT_DATE.Day
```

Hope this helps someone else.